# Downgrade from Java 1.8.0_111 to 1.8.0_102 on ubuntu 16.04?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, java-8, ubuntu-16.04, downgrade

Some java programs have stopped working on me recently, and I suspect it might have to do with the java version, so I've tried downgrading to an earlier version of java8 but with no success (already tried java7, java programs said they weren't compatible). Finding information has been a PITA though; openJDK and oracle don't seem to have downgrade options listed under the following:

```
apt-cache policy openjdk-8-jre
apt-cache policy oracle-java8-installer
```

I've also downloaded a tar I found from [here](http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk8u/jdk8u/archive/jdk8u102-b31.tar.bz2) (jdk8u-jdk8u102-b31.tar.bz2), but I have no idea how to install Java from it (just started using ubuntu recently).

Is there some easy way to install previous versions of Java8, with openJDK, Oracle, or other? And if the tar is my best bet, could somebody point me in the direction of a tutorial for how to install it?

Edit: Welp, just reinstalling java + a system restart seems to have fixed everything :/ . I think this question still deserves an answer though.

Comment: You could elaborate a little bit more in what whey did they stop working.

Answer (score 0):

You can install different version of java in different folder and update default version using update-java-alternatives command

Comment: Like I said; I have no idea where to install a previous Java8 version from, or how to directly install from the tar I have.